# "gatsby develop" cannot run in Mac M1

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gatsby, apple-m1

Iam using **gatsby 3.1.2** version with strapi as CMS, were i could not able to run **gatsby develop** and it is throwing this below mentioned error. Also attached the screenshot from terminal.

```
ERROR 

Invalid options object. Ignore Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options should be one of these:
   object { resourceRegExp, contextRegExp? } | object { checkResource }
   Details:
    * options misses the property 'resourceRegExp'. Should be:
      RegExp
      -> A RegExp to test the request against.
    * options misses the property 'checkResource'. Should be:
      function
      -> A filter function for resource and context.
```

[image]

**System Informations:**

- Gatsby CLI version: 4.0.0
- Gatsby version: 3.14.6
- Node version: v14.18.0
- NPM version: 6.14.15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps anyone, prior to this error (where it just doesn't run, without throwing any errors or clues) I had a hard time with `npm install`, but I was able to fix that by running the following:

```
brew reinstall vips
xcode-select --install
brew install gcc
brew reinstall vips
brew info vips
npm i
```